# Issue with container holding marquee animation - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I’m having an issue with a container holding the marquee and i’m not sure what’s causing it.

Essentially, the container is stretching way too far, causing the animation to flash across extremely fast (because the animation accounts for the width).

I don’t want to state a width for the marquee because I want the container to stretch to whatever its siblings width is.

I’ve created a fiddle to display what’s happening. In the fiddle, i’ve included the exact html included on my own webpage.

I assume there’s an issue with the css of one of the other elements, but what? What's causing the container to stretch to extreme lengths?

```
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uz9pG/
```

This is the jquery plugin marquee that i'm using http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jquerymarquee/

Answer (score 1):

Tables, fluid widths and overflow hidden tricks don't really get along well. You'll either need to change your code to use a different markup structure or put a fixed width on one the containing divs within your `<td>`.

Also, you have conflicting settings in your JS vs data-attributes in your markup. `<div data-duration="2000" data-direction="right" class="marquee">`

Here's a working version. http://jsfiddle.net/uz9pG/2/ Takes a second for the marquee to start. You'll need to adjust your margin code to sort that out. This one removes the tables altogether but you can just as easily add a fixed width to something like your `.module_content` div if that works for your design.

```
.module_content {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think there's still something we're missing. I've tried other jquery plugins that don't do this. Setting a fixed width isn't an option unfortunately. The slider needs to span the width available (but not extend past that width). Removing the table from equation does fix the issue. But how can I remove the table without removing the marquee div within the table (using jquery)? Thank you for your support.